# Add variables from user input fields

Tags: javascript

```
 var c7 = document.getElementById("C7");
 var c8 = document.getElementById("C8");

function subtotal_conturi() {
   var c7_number = parseFloat(c7.value);
   if (isNaN(c7_number)) c7_number = 0;
   var c8_number = parseFloat(c8.value);
   if (isNaN(c8_number)) c8_number = 0;
  
  c10 = c7_number + c8_number;
   document.getElementById("subtotal-c10").value = c10;

   return c10;
}


 var c12 = document.getElementById("C12");
 var c13 = document.getElementById("C13");

 function subtotal_investitii() {
   var c12_number = parseFloat(c12.value);
   if (isNaN(c12_number)) c12_number = 0;
   var c13_number = parseFloat(c13.value);
   if (isNaN(c13_number)) c13_number = 0;

  c20 = c12_number + c13_number;
   document.getElementById("subtotal_c20").value = c20;

   return c20;
 }

 function add(c10,c20) {
   return c10+c20;
   console.log(add(c10,c20));
 }
```

I have 2 functions (c10 and c20) that represent the sum of some variables which I get from users (c10 is the sum of c7 and c8 input fields). I am trying to get the sum of c10 and c20. I removed 'var' from them so that I could access them globally but I stil cannot. How could I solve this?

Comment: The Information you provided is less, please also a JSfiddle link with the current working code. It could be that you are calling the fn wrong / improperly. From the above example we only see the actually fn that do calculation but where do you call them, when in the lifecycle are they invoked etc etc still remain unawsered

Comment: Don't use JSFiddle when you can use the built-in snippet.

Comment: Quick trick would be removing declaration of variable from add function. If you declare that Javascript will not look for global variable which you created in first place.

Comment: @NishantSVispute using a code snippet in SO is way faster

Comment: it might really help if you could add the HTML to you code so we could try a working snippet. Are you seeing any JS errors in your browser's dev tools, because I'm suspicious of the inconsistency in naming: subtotal-c10 versus subtotal_c20

Comment: @coder the problem in your link is that its in romainan language.. maybe will give it a try it was in English

Comment: @NishantSVispute you tagged the wrong person, it should be DanaSugu

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to access variables from a function without calling the function that creates it.

```
function subtotal_conturi() {
    let c7 = document.getElementById("C7").value;
    let c8 = document.getElementById("C8").value;
    
    let c7_number = parseFloat(c7);
    if (isNaN(c7_number)) c7_number = 0;
    let c8_number = parseFloat(c8);
    if (isNaN(c8_number)) c8_number = 0;
  
    let c10 = c7_number + c8_number;

   return c10;
}

function subtotal_investitii() {
    let c12 = document.getElementById("C12").value;
    let c13 = document.getElementById("C13").value;
    
    let c12_number = parseFloat(c12);
    if (isNaN(c12_number)) c12_number = 0;
    let c13_number = parseFloat(c13);
    if (isNaN(c13_number)) c13_number = 0;
  
    let c20 = c12_number + c13_number;
    
   return c20;
}

function add() {
    let x = subtotal_conturi() + subtotal_investitii();
    return x;
}
```

If you already call the functions elsewhere in the code (maybe by onload or whatever) make the variables you need for it global by defining them without giving them a value outside the function.

example:

```
var c10;
var c20;
function subtotal_conturi() {
        let c7 = document.getElementById("C7").value;
        let c8 = document.getElementById("C8").value;
        ...
        c10 = c7_number + c8_number;
}
```

Then you can access them on the add() function like this:

```
function add(c10,c20) {
     ...
     x = c10 + c20;
     return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both ways but I still cannot get it right.

Comment: How do you try to call the functions? Post that section of the code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying, but maybe this snippet (let's call it a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) can inspire you. It uses a hidden input with some [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to determine the values for calculation and output. For handling (change, keyup) [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is used.

```js
calcSum(document.querySelector('[data-sum="C10"]'));
calcSum(document.querySelector('[data-sum="C20"]'));

document.addEventListener('change', handle);
document.addEventListener('keyup', handle);

function calcSum(origin) {
  const sum = origin.dataset.for.split(',')
    .map(v => +(document.querySelector(`#${v}`).value))
    .reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
  origin.value = sum;
  document.querySelector(`#${origin.dataset.sum}`).textContent = sum.toFixed(2);
}

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.type === 'number') {
    return calcSum(origin.closest('div').querySelector('[type=hidden]'));
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  margin: 5px;
}

span[data-sum] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" id="C7" value=23.12>
  <input type="number" id="C8" value=32>
  <input type="hidden" data-for="C7,C8" data-sum="C10">
  <span title="Sum #C7, #C8">Subtotal: 
    <span data-sum id="C10"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" id="C12" value="238.76">
  <input type="number" id="C13" value="1.3">
  <input type="hidden" id="calc_sub11_12" data-for="C7,C8,C12,C13" data-sum="C20">
  <span title="Sum #C7, #C8, #C11, #C12">Total:
    <span data-sum id="C20"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help my problem but once I solve it I could try the mininal reproductable way.